# Why File path is not taking when i run as packaged jar?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

I wrote a line for getting json file under resource folder in spring boot. When I run through eclipse IDE, the path is correct but when build it and run as jar file path is not taking correctly.

```
private static Map<String, Map<String, String>> configs;
configs = mapper.readValue(
                    new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "main"
                            + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "test" + File.separator + "text.json"),
                    new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>() {
                    });
```

Comment: Are you sure that when you run your jar you have file  `${user.dir}/src/main/resources/test/text.json` exists?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "test" + File.separator + "text.json")
```

try using this provided by spring core.

```
new ClassPathResource("test/text.json").getFile()
```

Comment: Getting the below error ---------java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test/text.json] cannot
 be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system
: jar:file:/D:/version-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/test/
text.json

Comment: Hi you are sure your text.json file is place under


/src/main/resources/test/text.json

Comment: Yes.--configs = mapper.readValue(
     new ClassPathResource("test/text.json").getFile(),
     new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>() {
    });------------------------------------But not able to get the file.Please see my post.I am not able to read and map that json.Its showing...................................................java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test/configData.json] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system : jar:file:/D:/app-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/test/ text.json

Comment: yes got it. when 

      new ClassPathResource("test/text.json").getFile() 

return exception because it's internally calling AbstractResource class in this class getFile throwing exception. getInputStream implemented into ClassPathResource class itself, So it's work. Thanks for catch.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at Spring documentation [Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader)

also when you launch your application from IDE then your application is not archived to **jar** and therefore you can access files simply through a **path**,  but when you launch your application from jar archive `java -jar my.jar`  you should search your file in the classpath, but you can also find files outside your launched jar archive

also, remember that files from the **test** directory do not fall into the jar archive, these files and classes in the **test** directory will be available only during tests execution before building the jar archive

from Spring Boot documentation

> "classpath:com/myapp/config.xml" => Loaded from the classpath
>
> "file:/data/config.xml"            => Loaded as a URL, from the filesystem

also, you can use [ClassPathResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) without `classpath:` and `file:` prefix

for example, you have two files:

```
+-src
  |  +-main
  |  |  +-java
  |  |  |  +-com
  |  |  |  |  +-example
  |  |  |  |  |  +-app
  |  |  |  |  |  |  +-MyApp.java 
  |  |  +-resources
  |  |  |  +-foo.json
  |  |  |  +-my-folder
  |  |  |  |  +-bar.json
```

with **ClassPathResource** you will find the files when you run from the IDE and when from the **jar** archive

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp, args);

        ClassPathResource fooClassPathResource = new ClassPathResource("foo.json");
        System.out.println(fooClassPathResource.exists());

        ClassPathResource barClassPathResource = new ClassPathResource("my-folder/bar.json");
        System.out.println(barClassPathResource.exists());
    }
    
}
```

console output:

```
true   
true
```

Comment: Great.This is working.But not able to get the file.Please see my post.I am not able to read and map that json.Its showing...................................................java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test/configData.json] cannot
 be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system
: jar:file:/D:/app-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/test/
text.json

Comment: Now its working.thank you all. Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("test/text.json");......we cannot use resource.getFile we need to use resource.getInputStream  .If you try to use resource.getFile() you will receive an error, because Spring tries to access a file system path, but it can not access a path in your JAR.

Comment: you are welcome, did you try to use `resource.getPath()` ?

Comment: also with `ObjectMapper` you can use `inputStream` from `resource`, for example: 
 `mapper().readValue(resource.getInputStream(),new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>() {
            });`